# Gnome tweak icon change doesn't take on dock or desktop

Tags: icons, gnome-tweaks

Ubuntu 20.04 on Lenovo laptop running Tweaks 3.34 with Gnome shell 3.36.9 and GTK 3.24.20. I selected Humanity icons with High Contrast applications theme. The Humanity icons appear in Nautilus but not in the dock or on the desktop with exception of apps installed in snap, e.g. Thunderbird. If I change the applications theme to Yaru, then the Humanity icons appear on the desktop but still not in the dock. I have tried alt/f2 and r. I have tried logging off and back on. I have restarted. No luck with any of the above. Suggestions anyone?

Answer (score 0):

Forgot to try alt/f2 and r after changing the theme to Yaro. Icons in dock are okay now. Perhaps some themes are incompatible with some icons?